# How to make this sidebar go down on mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

On mobile device the the sidebar is shown above my products. I want that it should go down the my products.
The side bar is on the left and content on the right. Also is there a better way to create a sidebar than what I did here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/3pLnc4y1/

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>   
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2">
  Home/Categories
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-10">
<h2>My shop</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
 sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
 sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
 sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
 sdsd
</div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp). I created a sample Codepen for you here: https://codepen.io/CWSites/pen/pqGowo

The code itself can be however you like, for simplicity I just made a few divs.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    Sidebar Here
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is where the magic happens. You will need a containing div with some flex styles applied in order to use flexbox. Your sidebar and your content divs will also need some flexbox code of their own. In my sample I have the media query set for screens 600px and smaller but you can adjust that to whatever you like.

Starting off you'll want your sidebar order to be 1 so it displays first going left to right, however on a smaller screen I flip the flexbox order so sidebar is now 2 and content is 1.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  order: 1;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  order: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {     
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .sidebar {
    order: 2;
  }

  .content {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

When working with Flexbox, I find this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use have to use use the order class utility :

**Doc** : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#reordering

**JsFiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/b9ejhstw/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 order-md-last">   <!-- <--- HERE  --->
<h2>My shop</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    sdsd
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    sdsd
</div>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        Home/Categories
    </div>
</div>
```